# Insert new row duplicating old one and updating it with new data in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

1. car_consistent (it gets filled and never changes)

| id | type | brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dream | ferrari |

2. car_expanded

| version_id (pk\seq) | user_that_updated_version | parent_id (id from car_consistent) | current (boolean) | engine | color | length | wheelbase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prime | 1 | true | 4.7 | red | 4,480 | 2,581 |

When new car version shows up - older is not replaced, you get something like this:

| version_id(pk\seq) | user_that_updated_version | parent_id (id from car_consistent) | current (boolean) | engine | color | length | wheelbase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prime | 1 | false | 4.7 | red | 4,480 | 2,581 |
| 2 | mike | 1 | true | 6.5 | red | 4,480 | 2,581 |

So when you join tables on id = parent_id where current = true you get full representation of the car in its current state.
It helps me to track versions and users that made them. Also i can rollback fast.

I am getting updates in following format: "Mike said engine is 6.5 now."

So what i need to do:

1. Insert new row that is duplicating older one except its id, user_that_updated_version and changed column (engine here).
2. Set older version current column (or all others with same parent_id) to false and new version current column to true.

On 1) i tried and failed with following query:

```
WITH new_version_id AS (INSERT INTO car_expanded (user_that_updated_version, parent_id, current, engine, color, length, wheelbase)
                        SELECT user_that_updated_version, parent_id,    current, engine, color, length, wheelbase
                        FROM car_expanded where id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM car_expanded WHERE parent_id = 1)
                        RETURNING id)
UPDATE car_expanded SET user_that_updated_version ='mike',engine = 6.5
WHERE id = (SELECT * FROM  new_version_id);
```

It inserts new row, but does not update it.

And i cant even imagine how to implement task 2) in that single query.

Yes, im trying to do it in single query because it is executed from java code.

I would be grateful for any ideas. Thanks in advance.

-----update-----

Feels like following query can solve it:

```
WITH prev_version AS (SELECT user_that_updated_version, parent_id, current, engine, color, length,  wheelbase
    FROM car_expanded
    WHERE parent_id = 1 AND current = true
    LIMIT 1),
     unmark_all AS (UPDATE car_expanded SET current = false WHERE parent_id = 1)
INSERT INTO car_expanded (user_that_updated_version, parent_id, current, engine, color, length, wheelbase)
VALUES (
        'mike',
        prev_version.parent_id,
        true,
        6.5,
        prev_version.color,
        prev_version.length,
        prev_version.wheelbase
       )
```

But now im getting [42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "prev_version".

Comment: It looks like you only need an insert but to understand it better, where does that Id come from? Sounds like that would be version_id but it is all 1 in the sample. And as a side note, you could two separate SQL in one query to the backend.

Comment: @CetinBasoz id is auto generated, that is why i cant just select *. Edited.
And thanks for the note, ill check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(would be a mess in comments)
Based on your update, instead of Values, you would use select:

```
WITH prev_version AS (SELECT user_that_updated_version, parent_id, current, engine, color, length,  wheelbase
    FROM car_expanded
    WHERE parent_id = 1 AND current = true
    LIMIT 1),
     unmark_all AS (UPDATE car_expanded SET current = false WHERE parent_id = 1)
INSERT INTO car_expanded (user_that_updated_version, parent_id, current, engine, color, length, wheelbase)
select
        'mike',
        prev_version.parent_id,
        true,
        6.5,
        prev_version.color,
        prev_version.length,
        prev_version.wheelbase
       from prev_version;
```

[DBFiddle demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f5a3463656317508c0be6c2fa13fad6b)

Answer (score 2):

in simple approach:

1. first update the current to false in the latest current record in table "upd".
2. insert the new record with some new values and some values from table "upd".

   ```
    create table car_consistent (id smallint, type varchar(10), brand varchar(10));
    create table car_expanded (version_id serial, user_that_updated_version varchar(10), parent_id smallint,
    current boolean, engine varchar(10), color varchar(10), length integer, wheelbase integer);

    insert into car_consistent values (1, 'dream', 'ferrari');
    insert into car_expanded (user_that_updated_version, parent_id, current, engine,
                    color, length, wheelbase)
                    values  ('prime', 1, true, '4.7', 'red', 4480, 2581);

    -- insert 2nd record to update engine to 6.5:
    with upd as (update car_expanded set current = false where parent_id = 1 and 
                version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) FROM car_expanded WHERE parent_id = 1)
                returning *
        )
    INSERT INTO car_expanded (user_that_updated_version, parent_id, current, engine,
                    color, length, wheelbase)
                    SELECT 'mike', parent_id,    
                    true, '6.5' , color, length, wheelbase
                    from upd where parent_id = 1 and version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) 
                    FROM car_expanded 
                    WHERE parent_id = 1);

    select * from car_expanded;

    -- insert 3rd record to update engine to 7.5:
    with upd as (update car_expanded set current = false where parent_id = 1 and 
                version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) FROM car_expanded WHERE parent_id = 1)
                returning *
        )
    INSERT INTO car_expanded (user_that_updated_version, parent_id, current, engine,
                    color, length, wheelbase)
                    SELECT 'john', parent_id,    
                    true, '7.5' , color, length, wheelbase
                    from upd where parent_id = 1 and version_id = (SELECT MAX(version_id) 
                    FROM car_expanded 
                    WHERE parent_id = 1);                       

    select * from car_expanded;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have a `car_expanded` table and for example table has a one record:

| version_id | user_that_updated_version | parent_id | current | engine | color | length | wheelbase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prime | 1 | true | 4.7 | red | 4,480 | 2,581 |

After inserting this data:

```
INSERT INTO car_expanded (
        version_id, 
        user_that_updated_version, 
        parent_id, 
        current, 
        engine, 
        color, 
        length, 
        wheelbase 
    ) 
    values (
        1, 
        'mike', 
        1, 
        true, 
        6.5, 
        'red', 
        4480, 
        2581
    )
```

You want to view this result:

| version_id | user_that_updated_version | parent_id | current | engine | color | length | wheelbase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | prime | 1 | false | 4.7 | red | 4,480 | 2,581 |
| 1 | mike | 1 | true | 4.7 | red | 4,480 | 2,581 |

Maybe `car_expanded` table has a primary unique key field, for example `table_id`, so our query sample:

```
with new_car as (
    INSERT INTO car_expanded (
        version_id, 
        user_that_updated_version, 
        parent_id, 
        current, 
        engine, 
        color, 
        length, 
        wheelbase 
    ) 
    values (
        1, 
        'mike', 
        1, 
        true, 
        6.5, 
        'red', 
        4480, 
        2581
    )
    returning table_id, parent_id 
)
update car_expanded car 
set 
    current  = false 
from 
    (select * from new_car) new_data
where 
    car.parent_id = new_data.parent_id and 
    car.table_id <> new_data.table_id;
```

This query will update records field set to `current=false` that have `parent_id=(new inserted parent_id)`, but for does not updating inserted record, we must be control `table_id` (primary unique key of `car_expanded` table) field.

Comment: He doesn't want to do an insert with hard coded values.

Comment: @‎ЦетинБасоз‎  - I understand, but this is a sample code